# Is it possible to increase a snow golem's range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, simply put, I want to increase the range at which snow golems notice mobs and start throwing snowballs at it. I hoped generic.followRange would do the trick but it doesn't seem to change their behaviour at all. So I was wondering if there is a way to increase that range?

Edit: generic.followRange makes them able to keep attacking targets from really far away, but only after first noticing them, which is still the normal range.

Comment: I am assuming this is for creative mode correct?

Comment: If `generic.followRange` doesn't do it, I don't think there is a way. Apart from teleporting them to mobs and back again. :D But that would still require them to notice the mob in time. I guess you could wait with the teleportation back until they throw a snowball, but it just won't look like they are in the place they are supposed to be in. It's probably only possible by disabling their snowballs (just `/kill` the snowballs) and letting your commands take that job from them, by summoning your own snowballs with the correct directions (requires a bit of scoreboard Math, but it is possible).

Comment: @Fabian Röling I just came back here to ask a new question and checked this one before, funny thing is, my new question is exactly about the solution you gave. As in, how to I correctly summon an arrow/snowball in the direction a mob is looking (and it actually flying in that direction).
I also posted this as an actual question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354812/summoning-an-arrow-aimed-at-a-mob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remembered I asked this years ago and I have an answer, sort of.

There is a new command, /damage, since 1.19 or 1.20 I believe, that allows you to damage a single entity for a chosen amount. It also allows you to choose which entity did this damage, by combining this and follow_range, you can increase aggro range by making the snow golem (or any entity for that matter) take 0 damage from entities that enter its "custom" range. An example of how this could work:

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:zombie] run execute at @e[type=minecraft:snow_golem,distance=..50] run damage @e[distance=..1,type=minecraft:snow_golem,limit=1,sort=nearest] 0 minecraft:generic_kill by @s from @s
```

This command is structured weirdly because both `/damage` itself and the `by` target can only target one entity. So I execute the command centered around the target entities I want the golems to attack from further (zombies), and chose range 50 for this. then I execute `at` all nearby snow golems as to not lose the `as` from the previous execute because that is important since the zombies need to be the target of the `@s` in the `/damage` command. The `/damage` is executed in a small area around its target location and targets the nearest snow golem at that location. Since this all hapens within a single tick the golem shouldn't have moved at all and this will effectively target each golem, just in a slightly roundabout way.

If you also give the snow golems increased `follow_range` with something like `/execute as @e[type=minecraft:snow_golem] run attribute @s minecraft:generic.follow_range modifier add 0-0-0-0-0 T 50 add` you should have golems with increased range. (This can also be used very effectively on skeletons)
The `0-0-0-0-0` is just a very short UUID*, you can't use the same one for multiple modifiers of the *same* attribute, the `T` is just a name, that one doesn't have to be unique at all.

*From what I understand, a UUID consists of 5 parts of symbols (0-9, A-F), seperated with a -, entities have `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as their UUID format for example, I just use `0-0-0-0-0` because it's quick to type and fits the format.