# How do I summon an arrow to move in direction that I'm facing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to summon an arrow that will move forward like it was shot out of a bow, in the direction im facing in 1.16.1 minecraft. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Im playing java edition.

Comment: this question already have an answer here:   https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339637/how-to-use-coordinate-systems-for-motion-nbt   or here:    https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354812/summoning-an-arrow-aimed-at-a-mob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you will need probably will involve the editing of NBT tags to set the speed and direction.

NBT tags go in the `{}`s at the end of the `/summon` command:

```
/summon arrow ~ ~ ~ {NBT}
```

I'm afraid I can’t provide a full answer at this time, but you can consider looking at these Minecraft Wiki articles:

- [Entity format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Entity_format)
- [Arrow](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow)